# ConEmu + Cygwin + Emacs gives strange behaviour

Tags: emacs, cygwin, conemu

I'm using cygwin through ConEmu, and I like to use emacs in terminal mode ("-nw") as my editor. It seems to work correctly through cygwin directly, but when running through ConEmu I get strange behaviour that is a bit complex to describe and so difficult to search for a solution to the problem.

- I open a file i.e. "emacs -nw ~/.bashrc"
- If e.g. I enter a newline, i.e. press enter, the whole file moves down one line as expected, but the menu bar above the file disappears.
- If I move further down the file i.e. press the down arrow several times, the cursor moves down as expected. However when I now enter a newline, not only the text below the cursor moves down, in fact the whole file moves down a line in the terminal, and the menu bar above disappears as before.
- I think there are other odd behaviours but maybe that is enough to identify the problem. I guess it is some error in displaying the appropriate state of the file to the terminal and so breaks the connection between what is displayed and the actual state of the editing of the file.

Please let me know if anyone can help, I'm so close to getting a workable terminal in windows that it would be very annoying to let this hold me back.

Many thanks,
kerzane.

Comment: Do you have the issue without ConEmu?

Comment: No, in normal cygwin terminal the issue doesn't arise. Thanks.

Comment: ConEmu version? And how exactly do you run cygwin in ConEmu?